# C include guard

Tags: c++, c, include-guards

When `file1.c` includes `inc.h` (containing the include guard `#ifndef INC_H`) for the first time, the `#define INC_H` is performed. But now, when another `file2.c` includes the same `inc.h`, is the macro `INC_H` already defined, all it's the same story and previous definition is not propagated here?

Comment: What this question could use is a good dose of [sample code](http://sscce.org/), some that's complete & concise.

Comment: It's explicit, no sample code needed.

Comment: @James: it's not explicit enough. You haven't specified if you compiled the two C files separately or as a single compilation unit.

Comment: @Mat, really? Common sense says he's not concatenating two C files. It's a straightforward question.

Comment: @BrettHale: common sense answers the question once you've learnt a bit of C and thought about it.

Comment: Mostly, I can't quite understand the English. Sample code should clear up exactly what James is asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But now, when another file2.c includes the same inc.h, is the macro INC_H already defined,

Yes and No. It depends.

- If `file2.c` includes some header which includes `inc.h`, then **yes**, `INC_H` is already defined for `file2.c`. This is true for any level of inclusion.
- Else, **no** it is not already defined.

Guards prevent header from being included in a file, indirectly or directly, more than once!

Comment: It contradicts another answers claiming, that two compilations of distinct `*.c` files don't share any new definitions.

Comment: Oh no, read to quickly. First bullet is meant as `file2.c <- other.h <- inc.h`, right? Then this answer is absolutely rigorous. Sorry.

Comment: @James: Yes, that is right. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The macro definition is not preserved between separate compilations.

Answer (score 2):

When you complile `file2.c`, the compiler starts afresh. Whatever preprocessor symbols got defined when `file1.c` got compiled play no part during the compilation of `file2.c`.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions are not propagated between `*.c` files.  If they were, you would not need `*.h` files in the first place.  (However, you can `#include` a `*.c` file, but that is another story.)

Answer (score 0):

No, think a moment what "`#include`" does. It essentially copies the contents of the header file to the place where it is included.

So `INC_H` will be defined the first time `inc.h` is included in a `.c` file. However, this changes nothing for another .c file.

Include guards are useful when include files have other include into it. In these cases you can avoid trouble using the guards.